# Не компилится код при использовании Convert в XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Вот код сразу:

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
       <Button
           Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=Win, Converter={StaticResource ConverterCS}}"
           Width="{Binding Height}"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

C#:

```
class ConverterCS : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value / 3;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Как только я вписываю свойство `Converter={StaticResource ConverterCS}`, то код сразу перестаёт компилироваться, не выдавая ошибки.

Comment: Что такое `StaticResource ConverterCS`?

Comment: А где этот `StaticResource` подключен?